# Convert array in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of words in a .json file

Like this:

```
[
"city",
"river",
"car"
]
```

And i want to get an object for each word

Something like this:

```
[
    {
        word: "city",
        something: "..."
    },
    {
        word: "river",
        something: "..."
    },
    {
        word: "car",
        something: "..."
    }
]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Where does the "something" field in the output come from?

Comment: `const result = data.map(word => ({ word, something: "..." }));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let new_array = [];

for(let item of old_array)
{
 new_array.push({word:item, something:"..."});     
}
```